# Remove tag synonym? gulp.watch -> gulp-watch

Tags: discussion, support, tags, synonym-request, tag-disambiguation

One of the more confusing things about [gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gulp) is the difference between the built-in `gulp.watch()` function and the similarly named `gulp-watch` plugin. While both are used to watch files for changes neither is a drop-in replacement for the other. They are different in the way they work internally (leading to different failure scenarios) as well as the way they are used. I go into more detail about this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149563/javascript-gulp-watch-changed/36162027#36162027).

The matter wasn't helped by the fact that the [gulp-watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gulp-watch) tag used to lump both of those together. The [tag excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26609277/4) was about `gulp.watch()` (copied from the [API docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob--opts-tasks-or-gulpwatchglob--opts-cb)):

> Watcher of gulp to listen for file changes. This always returns an EventEmitter that emits change events.

While the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26609276/2) was about the `gulp-watch` plugin:

> The NPM package page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch
>
> How to install: npm install --save-dev gulp-watch

So I went ahead and tried to separate these two. I edited [gulp-watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gulp-watch) to be unmistakably about the plugin and created [gulp.watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gulp.watch) to be about the built-in.

Then I went on a retagging spree to tag all questions concerning the built-in with [gulp.watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gulp.watch). However three pages in the tag stopped working. Turns out a synonym [gulp.watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gulp.watch) -> [gulp-watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gulp-watch) was created.

So, what now? I get that having two tags that only differ by one character isn't ideal, but I'm still of the opinion that the two need to be separate. However I couldn't find a way to challenge tag synonyms.

The situation as it is now is certainly worse than it was before, because [gulp-watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gulp-watch) is now clearly about the plugin — while a huge swath of questions tagged with it isn't.

The only other option I see is editing [gulp-watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gulp-watch) again to be about both.

Comment: I was the one who alerted the mods about the retagging, which is why your tag went poof.  Given that users do not actually read tag descriptions, how do you propose getting users to actually use the correct tag?  Do we actually *need* a tag about watching in cases where the gulp-watch plugin is not being used?

Comment: What about using something more descriptive like [gulp-watch-plugin] (although it would be the only one to have that suffix =/)? I don't think having two tags so close to one another is healthy as cimmanon pointed out since it would need a lot of regular clean-up; having something more explicit in the tag name could help.

Comment: @cimmanon If users don't read tag descriptions then why **are** there tag descriptions? And why does the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts) state that they should be used to "Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag"?

Comment: @SvenSchoenung That's the theory... In practice, most users profit of the auto-completion when they type the tag and don't bother reading anything. Just look at some tags like [tag:stack-overflow].

Comment: @Kyll Yeah, I know, but I didn't like the defeatist attitude. I think your [gulp-watch-plugin] suggestion is a good pragmatic middle ground, even though this would make it different from tags for other gulp plugins like `gulp-concat` or `gulp-rename`. I might just go ahead with it.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung it's generally best to make a proposal such as that here on meta and gather feedback. That way, everyone knows what's happening and you'll possibly even gather people to help you out if/when a consensus is reached.

Comment: @Jon Clements Got it. Sorry about the mess.

Comment: @Sven no need to be sorry about it - thanks for your effort in trying to make the site better - it's genuinely appreciated. Possibly I was slightly early in thinking the new tag wasn't necessary so I syn'd them to prevent what (appeared at the time) were unnecessary tag edits, but since you've raised it now - everyone gets what you're trying to achieve and can have a discussion about what the best way is to do it :)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think having such closely related tags is a good idea. Users will often use one of them for the other, so much that they will both become ambiguous and fairly useless / frustrating to deal with.

A solution could be to create [gulp-watch-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gulp-watch-plugin). This has the benefit of showing the *"plugin"* word when typing the tag (so hopefully less tag misuse). The downside is that this would be the only tag in its category with such a suffix.

One could also add a notice on [gulp.watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gulp.watch) about using [gulp-watch-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gulp-watch-plugin) if the question is about the plugin. This could help a bit in educating users about which tag to use in which situation.

Note that if you intend to retag / edit / moderate a specific place on SO, you can come and ask the [SOCVR chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/) if you need help or company when doing it.

Comment: Thanks, Kyll. The more I think about it, the more I like this solution. It works well with auto-completion and it has the added benefit of coinciding with current usage of the [tag:gulp-watch] tag, which my original idea didn't. If I had to venture a guess I would say that only about 10%-20% of the questions in [tag:gulp-watch] are about the plugin. Your proposal minimizes the immediate need for retagging and should keep the clean-ups I have to do in the future to a minimum as well.

Comment: I'll leave this open for a few more days so people can voice any objections they might have (since it might not have received as many eyeballs on the weekend). If it doesn't get any pushback, I'll announce my intentions here and in the chatroom before going ahead with your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, but note that it's not necessary at all that you come into the room. In case you need any help or company we have many motivated reviewers who'd be happy to oblige. If you do any retagging just make sure to link back to this Meta in the edit description.